# Как лучше всего сделать такую кнопку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть два варианта такой кнопки (для десктоп и мобайл):

1. Только текст "Ответить на 7 вопросов" кликабелен (для десктоп)
2. Вся кнопка кликабельна вместе с "2 минуты" (для мобайл)

Если во втором варианте для мобайл можно картинкой всю кнопку поставить, то как лучше сделать такую кнопку в первом варианте? Может с помощью position? Учитывая то, что эта кнопка для экранов от 1920 до 998

И самый главный вопрос: Как вообще и с помощью чего лучше всего делать такие кнопки к которым прикреплены другие элементы и ещё в которых текст с имг?

Answer (score 3):

Честно говоря, как вам лучше\удобнее, так и делайте.

Лично я использовал вообще другой вариант, где "2 минуты" не кликабельно при помощи `pointer-events`, и позиционировал бы эту кнопку через `position: absolute`.

И у меня получился бы вот такой вариант:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0456b6;
  background: #005fcf;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 70px 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.2) inset;
}

.button .-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/LUnKrwb.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.button .-text {
  
}

.button .-text .-title {
  display: inline-flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 125%;
}

.button .-extra {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #010d1b;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: -40px;
}

.button .-extra .-num {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="-icon"></div>
  <div class="-text">
    <div class="-title">Ответить на 7 вопросов</div>
    <div class="-des">отправим предложение с 3мя вариантами разработки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="-extra">
    <div class="-num">2</div>
    <div class="-cou">минуты</div>
  </div>
</div>
```